# Population bias in survey leading to inaction

Tags: survey, bias, population, decision-theory, survey-sampling

This isn’t exactly an academic statistics question, but it is a real problem that I’m trying to understand with regards to bias in survey statistics leading to issues in real-world decision making.

I’m working with our local government organization, and they have used responses from a survey of our city’s general population as an indicator of the level of service for sports facilities.

For instance - the survey asks “Do you find the current state of softball fields adequate?”

But, of course - most of the general public doesn’t use the softball fields at all, and the local government is using this survey result as an indicator that they should not do anything to improve the state of softball fields.

Is there a name for this kind of logical fallacy or bias - where a general population is asked about something and this is used to justify inaction?

If this kind of logic were applied to its full end, there would be no existence of any kind of facilities whatsoever, as there are no majority of users for any kinds of facilities.

I’ve found the term “sampling coverage error” to describe the fact that the softball population was not surveyed - but i have NOT seen any research around the justification of inaction this leads to.

Is there a name for this kind of bias in decision making?

Comment: I would have serious problems interpreting any answers to "Do you find the current state of softball fields adequate" because the question is so vague and subjective.  Such surveys often have problems like this, ranging from meaningless questions to conflicting answers to lack of randomization to nonresponse.  From this perspective there's not even an opportunity for a logical fallacy here: it's just bad statistical practice.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

From the point of view of survey methodology, independently of the intention behind the poor question design, you could say that the question lacks **[validity or reliability](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=3205040)**.

In addition, if the question is intentionally vague or subjective (e.g. with political afterthoughts), it is likely **unethical**. It wastes the respondents' time and trust, and may make them less inclined to answer future surveys. This kind of question can be in contradiction with various ethical or normative principles, e.g. the UN Statistical Commission's [Fundamental Principles of Official Statistics](https://unece.org/statistics/FPOS):

> **2. Professional standards and ethics**
>
> To retain trust in official statistics, the statistical agencies need
> to decide according to strictly professional considerations, including
> scientific principles and professional ethics, on the methods and
> procedures for the collection, processing, storage and presentation of
> statistical data.

Relative to the bias this kind of question may lead to in decision making, this is not really a statistics question, but more a political one, so off-topic for this website. You could try asking it on https://politics.stackexchange.com.